# extjs container hbox height 100%

Tags: extjs, containers, hbox

I am new in extjs and just stuck on dynamic (percent) height in hbox setting.

here is my extjs code

```
"xtype": "container",
"layout": "fit",
"width": "100%",
"height": "100%",
"cls": "dashboard-layout dashboard-layout-1-2",
"items": [
  {
    "xtype": "dashboardpanelcontainer",
    "height": "45%"
  },
  {
    "xtype": "container",
    "layout": "fit",
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "45%",
    "layout":
      {
        "type": "hbox",
        "align": "stretch"
      },
    "items": [
      {
        "xtype": "dashboardpanelcontainer",
        "flex": 1
      },
      {
        "xtype": "ruban-dashboardpanelcontainer",
        "flex": 1
      }]
  }]
```

this peace of code is working fine and setting height to 45%

```
"xtype": "dashboardpanelcontainer",
"height": "45%"
```

second item as a container "xtype": "container" is setting height to 45% too, but the hbox items are not picking this 45%, the height of the hbox items are 0px

I cant use "xtype": "window" or "xtype": "viewport" needs to be inside "xtype": "window"

Any help how to set container hbox item height as percentage in my case 45%.

If i add style in hbox item, its not working too

```
"xtype": "dashboardpanelcontainer",
"flex": 1,
"style":
  {
    "height": "100%"
  }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [extjs 100% height in hbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704630/extjs-100-height-in-hbox)

Comment: i saw it, the answer is good for whose who can use  "xtype": "viewport", unfortunately i cant use viewport, i am using  "xtype": "container"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Percentage height is supported by Touch, but in Ext [only pixel height is officially supported](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-height)...

Then, your parent container has `layout: 'fit'` so it expects only one child. If you want to stack components vertically, use the `vbox` layout. Its [`flex`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Box-cfg-flex) option will let you size children relatively. It does not use percentage per se, but it works on ratios so it's the same.

Here's an example that closely looks like yours:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var ct = Ext.widget({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        xtype: 'container',
        style: 'background-color: pink;',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            bodyStyle: 'background-color: magenta;',
            flex: 45
        },{ // Filler for the remaining 15%
            xtype: 'component',
            flex: 15
        },{
            xtype: 'container',
            width: '100%',
            flex: 45,
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                bodyStyle: 'background-color: yellow;',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                bodyStyle: 'background-color: cyan;',
                flex: 1
            }]
        }]
    });

    // Since I've rendered to the body without using a viewport, I have to
    // refresh the layout if the window is resized...
    Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(function() {
        ct.doLayout();
    });
});
```

**Update**

Here's the HTML code I used. As you can see, there's nothing special with it...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../ext-4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all-debug.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../ext-4.2.1/ext-all-dev.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks rixo, but its still not working with height:'100%' (in the first container), if i change it to px when i see panel on the screen. Does your body element is the html has height specified in pixels or some style/css elements?

Comment: No, nothing of this kind... I've added my HTML markup for you to see. I've tested it in Chrome and Firefox with the same result. Anyway, if you really want to render to the body with height and width of 100%, you should really use a viewport, as suggested by the guy who answered your previous question.

Comment: Just for the test i add body element in this example, really i need around 60% of body, imagine it as one of the div elements in html, and other content of the page comes from html not from extjs, so i can't use viewport. I tried to even copy paste your example, i am getting an errors:
Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addCls'

Comment: Well, if you manage to give the container div some visible size, then it will work... See: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3il. There, I've given a px height to the div, but that's because of the iframe (I guuess the body collapse to its content size).

Comment: this is why my height was 0px, because it the content was empty and it use to collapse, if you want to see empty container you need to specified "shrinkWrap": false in your layout and it works. I will accept your answer, because it was a good start for me to change my original layout, thanks rixo for your help